# How to configure cursor shape in visual, visual block modes?

Tags: vimrc, visual-mode, cursor

I configure cursor shape in normal, insert, and replace modes with the following in my `vimrc`

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

I had assumed that `let &t_SV = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"` would do the same for visual mode but that doesn't seem to be the case :/

Is there a way to set the cursor shape for visual / visual block modes?

---

Edit: I see in `term.txt` helpfile the following:

```
    t_SI    start insert mode (bar cursor shape)        *t_SI* *'t_SI'*
    t_SR    start replace mode (underline cursor shape) *t_SR* *'t_SR'*
    t_EI    end insert or replace mode (block cursor shape) *t_EI* *'t_EI'*
        |termcap-cursor-shape|
```

i.e. no option listed for 'start of visual mode'

Comment: Can you not use `:h guicursor` option?

Comment: @3N4N this wouldn't work in the terminal iirc

Comment: I think vim can't do it.

Comment: Huh! Afaik Vim works with guicursor in my machine (and I am talking about Vim, not Neovim), but I have to double-check.

Comment: I checked. guicursor works in Windows Terminal (in Windows 11), but doesn't work in gnome-terminal or suckless terminal (in Ubuntu 20.04).